# Python: Duck-typing vs. Exception Handling

Tags: python, types, exception, duck-typing

A question on idomatic Python.  Suppose I have a function:

```
def a_function(list_of_things):
    for item in list_of_things:
        process_item(item)
```

Now suppose it's difficult for me to be sure that the input argument is a list.  Even now, I can hear the sweet pythonista chorus imploring me:  "Use duck-typing and exceptions!"

```
def a_function(list_of_things):
    try:
        for item in list_of_things:
            process_item(item)
    except:
        pass # . . . or something
```

And this is great, unless I pass in a map, or a string, or anything else that is iterable in a fashion that I find to be "wrong" for this particular application.

I don't write a ton of Python, but I manage to run into this and related situations often enough for it to annoy me regularly.  More generally, I want to use duck typing and exceptions, as seems to be the convention in Python, but getting an incorrect input type that passes my exception is possible in a lot of cases; so many that exceptions seem like the wrong answer as often as not (or at least quite often).

Even if exceptions *do* seem like the right answer, I'm still afraid when I use them, because what if I just haven't thought of the corner case where a bad type will pass, leaving my code, for lack of a better term, "ducked".

So I end up resorting to things like `type` and `isinstance`.  From my reading, it seems like explicit type checking is considered evil in Python, but what else to do?  Note that I almost never compose class hierarchies in my Python, so I don't have issues with subclasses and type checks, but others might.

I've thought of four possible answers, all of which seem equally likely to me:

1. You should be using exceptions, but you're doing it wrong.  Do it like this . . .
2. You should be using exceptions.  If bad types pass your checks, it's indicative of some problem in your design (what problem?)
3. You're doing the right thing.  Explicit type-checking is preferable in these situations.
4. You don't know about `<python thing for this situation>`?  Do some research!

Is is one of these, or something else?

**Note - I found a lot of questions on SO that beat around the bush about this, but I'm looking for people to speak to this specific "genre" of problem if they can.**

Comment: Can you include an example where this is actually a problem? If you don't know what input your function *might* get, such that it is possible to forget a corner case when using exceptions the problem might be one level higher.

Comment: Why would a map, string, or other iterable be "wrongly" iterable? Your example function doesn't depend on anything but iterability. Anyway, if you need, say, a sequence, you could try `isinstance(collections.Sequence)`, or `isinstance(collections.abc.Sequence)` in Python 3, but the usual way would be to just assume the caller did the right thing and rely on unit tests to make sure your code works.

Comment: @user2357112 - Suppose the hypothetical function `process_item` above writes each item to a file on its own line.  If I accidentally pass a string, instead of a list, I get each letter on a line in the output file.  It's not hard for me to imagine a case where I didn't mean to pass in a single string to that function, but the bug would pass silently.

Comment: Only check, if a wrong type leads to a wrong but valid answer (and a string is valid parameter, if you want a sequence of single characters). Anything else is up to the caller. The "bug" is not silent, because you have tests, to check, if the result is correct.

Comment: It's just an example, there are other cases, such as `add` - what an ambiguous function name, it looks like you can do math with a collection...

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson - Yes, that's an excellent example.

Comment: @Daniel - I think "Your unit/integration tests should catch such problems" is a good answer that wasn't covered by my hypotheticals above.  I at least would upvote it if you made it an official answer.

Comment: When using duck-typing... don't use exceptions to try to save the caller. You write a function that works with sequences and test it heavily with a list. If a user passes something else that doesn't work the way that you think it should, that's on the caller. If the bowels of your code blows up because of a funky data type... that's on the caller too. If it quacks like a duck but turns out to be an elephant... that's the elephants problem.

Comment: @tdelaney - Suppose I *am* the caller, and I'm terrified I'm passing in the wrong type to a function where I think it will pass in a buggy way.  Should I, the caller, then do explicit type checking on the argument before I pass it in?

Comment: As a caller you control the type of the argument, if not you simply pass the argument down from somewhere, so the caller of this function is responsible.

Comment: In a high-stakes environment, it makes sense to do heavy type checking with the knowledge that you have eliminated some possible uses of the code. So, by the time you hit terror, check away! For me, my lower data layers tend to be paranoid but for instance, instead of `isinstance(x, int)` I `int(x)` and let the exceptions fly. Also, caller should have been been testing the code (and reading the docs for the functions being called) ... you just have to decide who wears the big boy pants.

Comment: @Daniel - Right; as a caller I control the type of the argument, my question is about how best to exercise this control, and if explicit type checking is ever the appropriate way.  Your answer seems to say, "Don't ever check types, just write tests", which is something I hadn't thought of a certainly a valid response.

Comment: @tdelaney - I understand your ideas, I think.  I've also used tricks like `int(x)` to generate exceptions in the past, but it never sat totally right with me to put code in for the sole purpose of generating exceptions.  I've seen it from others though so perhaps this is the correct idiom.  In any case, thanks for the insights and I'd be happy to at least upvote those thoughts collected into an answer.

Comment: @tdelaney: using `int` on a unknown type is risky. Normally you don't want to allow strings which are valid numbers.

Comment: @Daniel - That jumped to my mind as well.  More general point taken, though.

Comment: @Daniel - I don't think its risky... If it can't be converted to an in `int`, `ValueError` is raised but we are in an error condition anyway. And why not allow strings that are valid numbers? Its all situation dependent of course, but when I am saving to a restricted data store, a "cast" lets my data layer handle more data types.

Comment: @charleslparker I don't typically do `int(x)` by itself, but when I am normalizing the data somehow. Maybe `json.dumps({'id':int(x)})`, or writing an xml doc to a datastore, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A best practice is, to be type agnostic. The `for`-loop raises an exception for any non-iterable type. The documentation should state clearly, that an iterable type is required. Functions using your function should have unit or integration tests, so that unexpected behavior is discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Type Check- 
You rightly mentioned that type checking is considered evil in Python.
We should care what an object does, not what it is. 
e.g - If I iterate on an input then my code should work for all iterable and I should never check it's type.

Exception handling - 
Let it throw exception, If we try to handle it either we will catch all kind of exception or we will miss any.

Lets validate behavior of python built-in and we can follow same -

1. hash(input)
   It will throw exception if input is not hash able-

   hash([1,2])

   TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Dictionary and Set both use hash() function. If you try to create dictionary with mutable key, it will also throw same exception

```
{[1,2]:"sample"}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Now try with set

```
set(([1,2], 5,6))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

2. filter(function_object, any_iterable)`

   filter(bool, 1245)

   It will throw 
   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

   Now apply iter on int object

   iter(1245)

   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

So filter internally use iter() and throw same exception what it get from iter()

`